# how to add Hibernate "createAlias" Child Restriction to parent Entity Restriction

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I've got a requirment where I need to apply a search keyword to name and and state of Parent entity (Customer) and also name attribute of child entity Order.

```
List<Criterion> aliasRestrictionsCriterion = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
Junction quotedLikeRestrictions = Restrictions.disjunction();
quotedLikeRestrictions.add(Restrictions.ilike("customerName", token, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
quotedLikeRestrictions.add(Restrictions.ilike("customerState", token, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
restrictions.add(quotedLikeRestrictions);
```

and to include the child table in the query I'm am doing the following

```
Criteria alias = criteria.createAlias("order", "order")
.add(Restrictions.ilike("order.name", token, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

Hibernate is generating the following query but what I need is to have order.name like comparison get added to the parent block.

```
CUSTOMER this_ inner join ORDER order_ on this_.ORDER_ID=order_.ORDER_ID where 
(lcase(this_.name) like ? or lcase(this_.state) like ?) and (lcase(order_.NAME) 
like ?)
```

what I want is to have (lcase(order_.NAME) like ?) inside the parent block. So I want is the following

(lcase(this_.name) like ? or lcase(this_.state) like ? or lcase(order_.NAME) like ?)

How can I achieve this ?

Update: this is how I'm calling the criteria

```
protected List getEntities(List<Criterion> restrictions, String aliasSearchToken) {
    Session session = currentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(getEntityClass());

    // apply restrictions.
    if (restrictions != null) {
        for (Criterion criterion : restrictions) {
            criteria.add(criterion);
        }
    }

    Criteria alias = criteria.createAlias("order", "order").add(Restrictions.ilike("order.name", searchToken, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

    List list = criteria.list();
    if (list != null) {
        return list;
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Update 2:

```
protected List getEntities(List<Criterion> restrictions, String aliasSearchToken) {
    Session session = currentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(getEntityClass());

    Junction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
    or.add(Restrictions.ilike("order.name", searchToken, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
    criteria.createAlias("order", "order").add(or);


    // apply restrictions.
    if (restrictions != null) {
        for (Criterion criterion : restrictions) {
            criteria.add(criterion);
        }
    }

    List list = criteria.list();
    if (list != null) {
        return list;
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

produced
    select ....... from CUSTOMER this_ inner join ORDER order_ on this_.ORDER_ID=order_.uid where (lcase(order_.NAME) like ?) and (lcase(this_.name) like ? or lcase(this_.state) like ?)

the orderName is just before but still not in the second or statement ... I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instea of adding the restriction to the Criteria (which creates an AND), you must add it to the `quotedLikeRestrictions` disjunction:

```
quotedLikeRestrictions.add(Restrictions.ilike("order.name", token, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

Comment: Thats what I tried first and I got this exception 
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: order.name of: com.company.dao.entities.Customer.

Comment: Probably because you create the alias after instead of creating it before. If you posted the complete Criteria creation code, it would be easier to help.

Comment: The current pattern is to create Restrictions in the service layer and pass it along to a DAOBase abstract class which based on which the current entity the DAO is for is grabbing the entity class and then calling criteria and I'm calling createAlias after the restrictions have been applied to the criteria. Should I be doing this before ?

Comment: Yes. If a restriction uses an alias, the alias must exist.

Comment: alias does exist. The query is generating the HQL fine it's just that the createAlias query is being added outside the parent query with an and and I need an or. Basically they searchKeyword can be on Customer.name, Customer.state or Customer.Client.name. Right now the SQL produced is Customer.name or Customer.state and Customer.client.name but I need an or on Customer.client.name

Comment: If you call createAlias() after the restriction is added, then the alias doesn't exist yet when the restriction is added, since createAlias() hasn't been called yet. createAlias() creates the alias. Once created, you can use it. Before it's created, you can't.

Comment: JB I've just updated the question with the code on how I'm calling the criteria.

Comment: But you haven't changed anything. The alias must be created **before** the restrictions are added, and the restriction on order.name must be added to the disjunction, not to the Criteria. If you don't change anything to your code, it won't change anything to the result.

Comment: Added an update2. I did this disjuntion before and did move createAlias before adding criteria but nothing changed just the order in SQL generated changed. The output is still the name. I think disjuntion works where there are two statements being added.

Comment: You are right. I Added order.name, customer.name and customer.state restriction to disjunction and it work. Thanks :)